# Is there a way to use multiple subplots for the same graphic using Seaborn?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'd like to have two plots (a scatter and a bar) shown on the same figure, with the following layout:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

But where 0 through 2 are filled with the first plot, and 3 is filled with the second. I've tried to use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4,figsize = (12, 10))` to create a 1x4 array of subplots, but when I call sns.scatterplot(..., ax=...), the `ax` argument is only able to accept one subplot label.

Is there a way, either in the subplot call or in the `ax` argument, to make a plot that is 75% of the width?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use the `fig, ax = plt.subplots(x,y,...)` code format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it using `plt.subplots()` by utilizing the keyword `gridspec_kwdict`, which takes dictionary that is passed to the GridSpec constructor used to create the grid on which the subplots are placed.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

np.random.seed(123)

data = np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)

x, y = zip(*Counter(data).items())

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [3, 1]}, 
                             figsize=(10, 4))

ax1.scatter(x, y)
ax2.bar(x, y)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't understand what the grid_spec kwargs were supposed to do in the subplot call, but your example really clears it up!